# How to change background-color of menu when item is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am still a beginner in React JS and I have problems with an example Menu.

I have a Menu, and I need that when the user clicks on the Menu, change the background so that the user knows which page he is on. I've done several tests, but I still haven't been able to.

Here is the code I put in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-resonance-6pwjh?file=/src/index.js

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try CSS `a:focus { background-color: ..... }`. When an `<a>` receives focus (gets clicked/tapped) the `:focus` selector gets triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-cherry-tpf50

**Note:** you need to add this dependency `"react-router-dom": "5.2.0"` in `package.json` file.

**React Code:**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="topnav">
          <NavLink to="/home" activeClassName="active">
            Home
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/news" activeClassName="active">
            News
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/contact" activeClassName="active">
            Contact
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/about" activeClassName="active">
            About
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**Styles:**

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

a.active {
  background-color: #1144ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: finally, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I managed something similar using styled components. It allows you to style a component based on props.

I have a page with recipes on it, and a category bar at the top with a list of proteins that the user can filter the recipes by. I created a state of activeCategory, and set it to 'all' by default, but it changes to whatever protein is selected when the user clicks it. I just passed that state to the categoryBar component as a prop and changed the background color of the selected protein when it was the active category.

You can see what I mean here, in CategoryBar.js line 12. Picker.js is the parent component, if you wish to take a look at the state.

https://github.com/Taouen/gobble/tree/master/src/components