# Check if page has on link to add class on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Function to check if, when I click on button on Navbar, go to the page and add a class 'Active' on it.

```
 checkToActive(to) {
           return (to === this.props.location.pathname) ? 'Active' : '';
    }
```

My button

```
 <Button state={this.checkToActive("/listening")} text="Listening" to="/listening" />
```

So.. when I click and go to the page /listening the button get 'Active' class, but when I go to /listening/subPage the button don't have it.. what can I do to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead of strict comparison

Comment: And how can I do that with my code? @95faf8e76605e973

Comment: You can use React **NavLink** instead of *Button* in Navbar, Documentation: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink or look at the working example in my answer.

Comment: I don't want really use NavLink I'm using <Link> on Button component.. I just want to make that function work with subpages :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router` v4 you can use `<NavLink>` if you want to do conditional styling or applying class when route matches.

It has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63135768/8996532

Comment: I don't want to use that, atm I'm using: <Link to={to}>{html}</Link> on my Button component.

Comment: By using this you don't need your custom function to validate url each time to apply your class, this is inbuilt feature. *For Example:* <NavLink to="/home" activeClassName="active">
            Home
          </NavLink>

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
 checkToActive(to) {
           return (this.props.location.pathname.contains(to)) ? 'Active' : '';
    }
```

Comment: can you share your code of /listening/subPage button?

Comment: <Button state={this.checkToActive("/listening/analytics")} text="Analytics" type="Secondary" to="/listening/analytics" />

Comment: I would suggest you console.log your this.props.location.pathname value. probably the url not match with your "to" variable in your subpage

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
checkToActive(to) {
    return this.props.location.pathname.includes(to) ? 'Active' : '';
}
```